# How to stop the default fading background-image effect in Chrome?

Tags: css, browser

When transitioning the background-image (which I thought is not possible before) there are different results in Chrome and Firefox. Firefox does the expected and just instantly replaces the background-image, but Chrome adds a fade to the transition. Although it is fancy, it adds some unwanted functionality. So how to remove/disable it for every visitor who is using Chrome?

Didn't find any solutions via search engines, but maybe I just don't know the correct keyword for this topic.

To see what I mean you can open the following example in different browsers.

```css
@keyframes test {
  0% {
    background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch");
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech");
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch");
  }
}

div {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  animation: test 3s infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I'm not searching for a workaround or other solution, I want to understand the cause and how to solve this problem. Thanks for the workaround answers tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using content property of `<img>` tag desired result is achieved.

```css
@keyframes test {
  0% {
content:url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech");  }
  50% {
    content: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch");
  }
  100% {
    content: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech");
  }
}


img{
-webkit-animation: test 3s infinite;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <img>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is solving the problem, but that's not answering my question. (added an edit to the question)

Answer (score 0):

try this, I think u want it this way

```
@keyframes test {
            0% {
                background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch");
            }
            49% {
                background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch");
            }
            50% {
                background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech");
            }
            99% {
                background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech");
            }

            100% {
                background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch");
            }
        }
```

Comment: @febadev just reduce the duration allowed to change, try the above code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is solving the problem, but that's not answering my question. (added an edit to the question)

Comment: @febadev the cross fade is supported natively by Chrome, Opera and Safari. Firefox hasn't implemented it yet. So this is the reason. I hope this solves your query

Comment: that's interesting, thanks. So how to tell Chrome to not do it? "supported natively" seems like it is possible to disable this ..

Comment: @febadev there's no option to disable it globally, u can use the above approach to get rid of it.

Comment: well thanks for your answer, seems like I have to use a different approach then. :)